# Why does ksh93 not support the %T format specifier of its built-in printf in AIX?

Tags: ksh, aix

We have tested the following commands with ksh93 `printf` in many AIX 5.3/6.1 systems, but they all failed with the same result.

Why is that?

```
# 
# oslevel -s                               
6100-07-09-1341
# 
# 
# ksh93 -c 'echo ${.sh.version}'
Version M-12/28/93e
# 
# 
# ksh93 -c 'printf "%T\n" "now"'      
ksh93[1]: printf: T: unknown format specifier
# 
#
```

Comment: does `printf '%(YY)T'` work as expected? If not, your version of ksh does not have ksh93h features. Probably too old.

Comment: ksh93e is ancient.

Comment: I mean the good thing is, you can still `printf 'date is %s\n' $(date '+%Y-%m-%d')` instead of `printf 'date is %(%Y-%m-%d)T\n'` and get the same result.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  As `date` just prints plain text verbatim anyway, `date '+date is %Y-%m-%d'` also works (regardless of shell).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant sure, but you might want one of the other features of `printf` on that thing :)

Comment: @OP No reason. It just doesn't support this.feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`%T` was added to ksh's `printf` in ksh93h released in 1999](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/blob/v1.0.6/src/cmd/ksh93/RELEASE#L2704)

Note the *`h`* suffix (where you have `e`) which indicates the version of ksh93.

The latest release of ksh93 by AT&T was ksh93u+ released in 2012. Development carries on as a community effort at https://github.com/ksh93/ksh with the latest release as of writing being ksh93u+m 1.0.6 from June 2023 and the one you'll likely want to switch to as it comes with hundreds of bug fixes.

Your ksh93e is ancient, released in 1996, even more ancient than AIX 5.3 or 6.1 (both EOL AFAICT).

If you're lucky, the `date` builtin was included in your build of ksh93 (I don't know if it was possible in ksh93e though as it was before ksh93 was made opensource), in which case you could do:

```
builtin date
date -d now '+the format you need: %FT%T%z for instance'
```

(with the `date -d` accepting the same date/time specification as `printf %T` does, not documented but you can find some examples [in that test file shipped with the ast-open source](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/tests/date.dat)) and instead of:

```
printf '%(format)T %<other-directive>' \
  some-time-spec \
  other-arg
```

You'd do:

```
builtin date
printf '%s %<other-directive>' \
  "${ date -d some-time-spec +format; }" \
  other-arg
```

Note that bash added a `%T` to its `printf` in 4.2 (2011) which implements a subset of ksh93's functionality in an incompatible way.

It doesn't support parsing dates such as `now` like ksh93 does. The only supported arguments are:

| bash | ksh93 equivalent | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `123456789` | `#123456789` | arbitrary epoch time¹ |
| `-1`² | `now` or `''` | current time |
| `-2` | none³ | time the shell was started |

zsh added a `strftime` builtin to format dates in 4.1.1 released in 2003 which should be contemporary to AIX 5.3 and may be another option for you.

For the current time in a format similar to that of ksh93's default `%T` one:

```
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ strftime '%a %b %e %T %Z %Y' $EPOCHSECONDS
Mon Jul 24 15:10:15 BST 2023
```

Parsing times with `strftime -r` (using `strptime()`) was only added in 4.3.3 (2007) though (contemporary to AIX 6.1).

---

<sup>¹ Note that in bash that can only be an integer number while in ksh93, that can have a decimal part (with `.` as radix character regardless of the locale).</sup>

<sup>² since 5.0, bash has a `$EPOCHSECONDS` special variable (copied from zsh) which can also be used there for the current time.</sup>

<sup>³ though you could always record that time at the start of your script with `starttime=${ printf '#%(%s.%N)T' now; }`</sup>

Comment: aaaargh, bash, why are you so… bash?!

Comment: Just for completeness: AIX5.3 is EOL since April 2015, on April 30. 2016 even the extended support ended. (https://robmcnelly.com/another-lifeline-for-those-on-aix-5-3-extended-support/). AIX 6.1 went out of support in April 2017 (https://community.ibm.com/community/user/power/discussion/61-support). A current AIX version (oslevel=7200-05-07-2346, bos.rte.shell is at 7.2.5.202) has ksh 93t+ from May 2009 installed.

Answer (score 1):

For AIX `printf` command `%T` is not a valid format specification. Please check the [manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=p-printf-command). Valid are
**a, A, d, i, o, u, x, X, f, F, e, E, g, G, c, s, b**

Comment: That link is about the standalone `printf` utility. The OP is talking about the `printf` builtin of ksh93 where a %T was added in version ksh93h so would hopefully be available in AIX 7.2. `printf --man` in ksh93 to see the manual of the builtin.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, on this page I see text: "The printf command works in a similar manner as the printf() C library routine. See the printf command." https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=shell-enhanced-korn-ksh93

Comment: If you want a man page for ksh93's `printf`, run `ksh93 -c 'printf --nroff 2> printf.1'`, you won't find one online. What time specifications it supports (which is very wide) is hardly documented.

Comment: (you can find some examples at https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/tests/date.dat though)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, IBM have own way to do the things and I am not sure they will implement something new if there is no real big demand. Unfortunately I have no access to AIX to check my assumptions. :)